# Can I get the IDs of all updated rows?

Tags: mysql

Suppose I do an INSERT / ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE in MySQL, and it updates a bunch of rows.  And the table has an autoincrement primary key.

Is there any easy way to get MySQL to tell me the IDs of the rows it just updated?

I know I can do another SELECT query that looks for the same constraints that the INSERT statement used, and that's not hard to write, but it seems like it could be much more efficient if MySQL could just keep track of the IDs for me.

I saw the trick in the manual about LAST_INSERT_ID for the case where there's a single inserted/updated row, but I'm wondering about the case where you're updating many rows.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is no. You'd need to give up extended insert and also check constraints before each insert/updating each row.

Comment: Mchl: Both the answers below give creative possible workarounds, but as asked, yours looks like the correct answer.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

Check this link once

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

It says

> If a table contains an AUTO_INCREMENT
>   column and INSERT ... UPDATE inserts a
>   row, the LAST_INSERT_ID() function
>   returns the AUTO_INCREMENT value. If
>   the statement updates a row instead,
>   LAST_INSERT_ID() is not meaningful.
>   However, you can work around this by
>   using LAST_INSERT_ID(expr). Suppose
>   that id is the AUTO_INCREMENT column.

To make `LAST_INSERT_ID()` meaningful for updates, insert rows as follows:

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id), c=3;
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I was referring to in the last sentence of my question.  Am I mistaken, or does that only work for single inserts?

Comment: Am i misunderstanding, or aren't you looking for a complete set of IDs which the INSERTs or UPDATEs created/affected? A sort of ALL_LAST_INSERT_ID()ish method? The above is to ensure LAST_INSERT_ID provides sane output when using, and it would work fine even if there was multiple inserts, or updates.

Comment: JustDanyul: Yes, I am.  But as I understand it, LAST_INSERT_ID (even with this trick) only holds a single ID value.  How do you get multiple values out of it?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, you don't :)

Comment: @Ken, sorry didn't saw your comment; as far I understand going through mysql docs; even `LAST_INSERT_ID` will hold the last inserted rows id. Not sure if it's at all possible to get id of all the rows being inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Efficiency aside, unless you use "Select for Update" (keep rows locked), you can't even be guaranteed that your subsequent Select will pick up the SAME rows you just updated so even a second read is not foolproof.
Triggers are fairly inefficient in MYSQL, but if you really need to do this, create trigger(s) [for update, insert] on the table in question, and have it insert the ID's of modified rows into another table.  You need to store `connection_id()` **(of your current session)** so you can separate rows inserted by statements on another session.